# Cannot resolve symbol "content_frame"

Tags: java, android

I seem to have a rather persistent error with my android studio. In each project I get the error cannot resolve symbol "content_frame" in lines like

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Setting_new()).commit();
```

I already did a "invalidate cache and restart", followed by a clean project and a rebuild project. While doing the rebuilding it gave the error

`Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

And on the right it said error: `cannot find symbol variable content_frame` I don't know if it is the error output the other message was mentioning.

Like I mentioned it is in each project, I made a new project with a menu drawer and just added this to the drawer and it gave an error. I've also downloaded a new installer and reinstalled android studio with it but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add fragment using

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Setting_new()).commit();
```

where container `R.id.content_frame` is the id of the `View` where your `Setting_new` will be displayed(added).

Add `Container View` in your Activity's xml file, something like...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here: `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Setting_new()).commit();`

Make sure that your FrameLayout, in which to add the Fragment exists in your .xml file:

```
 <!-- Frame Layout for Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:actionBarSize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to look for the id `content_frame` where your fragment would be loaded.

You can use something like below in your Activity's xml file:-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame" // ----------> id where fragment would be loaded.
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```